# Menu com dropdown dúvida

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu

Galera, fiz um menu com dropdown que da um probleminha. Ele assim que abre, ele estica a linha ao invés de ficar numa "box". Alguém pode me ajudar -> http://marciabelmiro.com.br/tg18/ link aonde se encontra o menu.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
width: 100%; 
height: 100%; 
position: absolute;
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.bar1,
.bar2,
.bar3 {
  width: 35px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #000;
  margin: 6px 95px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.texto{
    margin: 0px 0px -45px 0px;
    font-size: 27px;
    font-family: "Raleway", Times, serif;
}


/* Rotate first bar */

.change .bar1 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
}


/* Fade out the second bar */

.change .bar2 {
  opacity: 0;
}


/* Rotate last bar */

.change .bar3 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
a:link 
{ 
 text-decoration:none; 
} 
</style>
<body>
  <h1>
    <div class="texto">MENU</div>
    <div class="container" onclick="myFunction(this)">
      <div class="bar1"></div>
      <div class="bar2"></div>
      <div class="bar3"></div>

      <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content hide">
        <a href="#"><font size="5" color="#97a2a7">TREINAMENTO</font></a>
        <br/>
        <a href="#"><font size="5" color="#97a2a7">PÚBLICO ALVO</font></a>
        <br/>
        <a href="#"><font size="5" color="#97a2a7">OPORTUNIDADE</font></a>
        <br/>
        <a href="#"><font size="5" color="#97a2a7">ESTRUTURA</font></a>
        <br/>
        <a href="#"><font size="5" color="#97a2a7">PALESTRANTES</font></a>
        <br/>
        <a href="#"><font size="5" color="#97a2a7">DEPOIMENTOS</font></a>
        <br/>
        <a href="#"><font size="5" color="#97a2a7">GALERIA DE FOTOS</font></a>
        <br/>
        <a href="#"><font size="5" color="#97a2a7">LOCAL</font></a>
        <br/>
        <a href="#"><font size="5" color="#97a2a7">IDEALIZADORES</font></a>
        <br/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </h1>

  <script>
    function myFunction(x) {
      x.classList.toggle("change");
      document.getElementById('myDropdown').classList.toggle("hide");
    }
  </script>
</body>
</head>
</html>
```

Código do menu: l[ink donwload](http://molamestra.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/CODIGO-MENU.txt)

Comment: Como assim **"ele  ele estica a linha ao invés de ficar numa "box""** não entendi nem consegui visualizar o que vc quis dizer com isso...

Comment: tava upando o código aqui. O que acontece, assim que clico no menu ele desce a linha toda, esticando ela.

Comment: Jovem coloque o código direto na pergunta, evite links externos! Ainda não consegui entender o que vc quer dizer com "Estica a linha"... Que linha rss...

Comment: Amigo eu dei uma olhada no site e não vi um problema com o menu , eu n entendi o que você queria que acontecesse com o menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ao analisar o seu código, vi que é necessário ajustar o CSS referente ao menu. Como o site é responsivo, o menu precisa ser `position: absolute;` quando está no modo *desktop* e `position: relative;` no modo *mobile*. Vou listar o que deve ser feito:

Este abaixo é a `div` do menu:

```
/* MODO GERAL */
#le_body_row_1_col_3{
    z-index: 99;
    background: #fff;
}
```

Esses aqui você inclui no seu *@media rule* nos respectivos modos:

```
/* MODO DESKTOP */
#le_body_row_1_col_3{
    position: absolute;
}

/* MODO MOBILE */
#le_body_row_1_col_3{
    position: relative;
}
```

Esta é a `div` do conteúdo do menu (incluir no geral do CSS) que irá receber um espaçamento:

```
#myDropdown{
    padding: 10px; /* você pode alterar o valor que achar melhor*/
}
```

Fazendo essas inclusões, seu menu irá funcionar de modo independente e não irá *esticar a linha*. Veja como ficará:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Cara parabéns por ter resolvido e por ter entendido a pergunta dele, pq ninguém estava entendendo.

Comment: @Leandro :D Valeu! Eu saquei o que ele tava querendo dizer.

Comment: @dvd minha definição de "esticar a linha" foi atualizada!

Comment: kkkkkk foi mal por não saber me expressar bem pessoal. Fiquei pensando bastante tempo pra colocar algo diferente mas não me veio a mente